# Doxygen: How to get expected undocumented warnings when function is within a @name description

Tags: c++, doxygen

My doxygen configuration file specifies:

```
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
```

Meaning that I want to get a warning when a function is not documented, or partially documented. Because I have the requirement to have a code fully documented.

When I run doxygen on this code:

```
/** Description */
class A
{
public:
    void func1();
    int func2( int param1, int param2 );

    /** Partial description (missing a parameter)
     * \param param1 description
     * \return description
     */
    int func3( int param1, int param2 );

    /** Partial description (missing return value)
     * \param param1 description
     */
    int func4( int param1 );
};
```

I get 4 warnings:

```
warning : Member func1() (function) of class A is not documented.
warning : Member func2(int param1, int param2) (function) of class A is not documented. 
warning : The following parameters of A::func3(int param1, int param2) are not documented.
warning : return type of member A::func4 is not documented
```

Fine.

Now, if someone adds `/** \name */` before some function declarations, as below:

```
/** Description */
class A
{
public:

    /** \name first functions: */

    void func1();
    int func2( int param1, int param2 );

    /** \name second functions: */

    /** Partial description (missing a parameter)
     * \param param1 description
     * \return description
     */
    int func3( int param1, int param2 );

    /** Partial description (missing return value)
     * \param param1 description
     */
    int func4( int param1 );
};
```

Then we then only get two warnings:

```
warning : The following parameters of A::func3(int param1, int param2) are not documented:
warning : return type of member A::func4 is not documented
```

- The fact that `func1` has no documentation is not reported anymore. One could argue it has a documentation inherited from `\name` flag, but it definitely isn't documented!
- The fact  that `func2` missing arguments and return value is not reported anymore. Here, one couldn't honestly argue ;-), there are definitely undocumented parameters here and they must generate a warning.

My goal was to group member functions under sub-sections, like that:
[image]

**Is there any way to keep functions grouping under `\name` tag and get 4 warnings be reported? (by customizing the doxyfile content for instance?).**

**Acceptable answers would:**

- Find a way to have all warnings be reported even after a `\name` tag
- Or find another way than using `\name` tag to group functions with a title similar to "first functions:" and "second functions:" above that would preserve all warnings reported.

For now, the only alternative I have is to temporarily replace all `\name` and `@name` by `name(not a doxygen flag)`, generate documentation, fix warnings, then, replace `name(not a doxygen flag)` by `\name` back....really annoying. I'm looking for a better way to handle that.

Note: reported doxygen bug https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=780912